# Replace form on submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a scenario where the user will be presented with a multiple choice question, when they submit the form I would like for the form to toggle away and be replaced with the explanation of the answer.

I have the following view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#answerForm').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: this.method,
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#question").toggle(1000);
                $("#answer").toggle(1000);
            }
        });
        //alert("Submitted");
        return false;
    });

});
```

```
<div id="question">
    <span id="question-display">@Model.Question</span>

    <div class="answer-section">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "answerForm" }))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Responses.Count; i++)
            {
                    <div class="reponse">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedIndex, i, new { @class = "response-radio" })@Model.Responses[i]</div>
            }
            <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Answer" />                              
        }

    </div>
    <div id="testResponse">Form not submitted</div>
</div>
<div id="answer" style="display:none">
    @Model.Explanation
</div>
```

The issue is that while my form submission is not causing a redirect as intended the code in the 'success' function in js does not seem to be executing.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        QuizModel model = new QuizModel()
        {
            Question = "This is the question",
            Explanation = "This is the explanation",
            UserHasAnswered = false
        };

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Quiz/Submit
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(QuizModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int? selected = model.SelectedIndex;

            model.UserHasAnswered = true;
            model.Explanation = "Explication";

            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
            });

        }

        return Json(new
        {
            success = false,
        });
    }
```

Comment: might be because the ajax request is sending an error response.... add an error handler to the ajax request and see if it is getting called

Comment: if the ajax request is not returning error, then try $("#answer").show(); in the success statement after  $("#answer").toggle(1000);.

Comment: even if I put an alert in the success statement it never gets executed

Comment: Have u debugged in the browser as well as in code.Another thing why havent u provided controller name in Html.BeginForm("Index", "",.....